# A book about almost periodic functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, textbook-recommendation

Can anyone give me suggestions for new books about Besicovitch's almost periodic functions?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function) is quite nice, and there are given references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "a new", of what years?
Classics are always new-the books of Bohr, Levitan and Zhikov, Besikovich himself.
There is also a book of Corduneanu with standard name "almost periodic function" of 1989. Look also for Diagana 2013,  Albrecht Böttcher et al 2002,  Gaston M. N’Guerekata  2001,  Wolfgang Schwarz 1994,  S. Zaidman 1985 ...

Comment: My teacher wants a book with recent results, therefore Besicovitch's book, for example, is problematic (unless there's a newer edition than the 1935's one and then it's great).

Answer (score 2):

Corduneanu, Almost Periodic Oscillations and Waves. (2009, Springer)

Comment: Thanks, on what aspects does that book focus?

Comment: It's quite comprehensive (conjecturally, the publisher did not want to call the book "almost periodic function", because it would make it sound quaint, waves are more "sexy" (?!))

Comment: I'll look for it. Any other books?